# SQL Insert a record and use its Id to update another set of records foreign key

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables `CombinableOrders` and `Orders` and tempory table of order Ids

`Orders` contain a nullable `FK` to `CombinableOrders`

I create the record as follows

```
INSERT INTO 
  CombinableOrders ([Rank]) 
  VALUES (0)
```

I then need to associate that new combinableOrder with a set of orders derived from a temporary table of ids

```
UPDATE Orders
  SET Orders.CombinableOrder_Id = @Id_To_Original_Insert
  FROM Orders AS Orders
  INNER JOIN @Ids AS Ids
  ON Orders.Id = Ids.Id
```

How would i get the Id from the new created CombinableOrders?

Comment: Are you looking for `SCOPE_IDENTITY`?

Comment: Or the SQL output clause? I mean, you DO Know SQL, right?

Comment: I know enough to get me into trouble, however i think scope_identity might be what im looking for, as this is running in a stored procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just want to declare a variable of the right type

```
DECLARE @id INT
```

and then set it using [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190315.aspx) after the insert

```
SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Alternatively you could output in the insert using the [`OUTPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause, but that's may be slightly more complicated in your case.